# Does $\mathbb{E}[X|X < c]$ differentiate to $f(c)\left(c -\mathbb{E}[X | X < c]\right)P(X < c)^{-1}$?

Tags: solution-verification, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ denote a continuous random variable with support $\mathbb{R}$ and PDF $f$. It seems to me that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d \mathbb{E}[X | X < c]}{dc} &= \frac{d}{dc} \frac{\int_{-\infty}^c x f(x) dx}{P(X < c)} \\
&= \frac{cf(c)P(X < c) - f(c)\int_{-\infty}^c x f(x) dx}{P(X < c)^2} \\
&= \frac{cf(c)P(X < c) - f(c)\mathbb{E}[X | X < c]P(X < c)}{P(X < c)^2} \\
&= \frac{f(c)\left(c -\mathbb{E}[X | X < c]\right)}{P(X < c)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Is this indeed correct? I am asking only because I can't find this anywhere on MathSE when I looked for it (although it surely must be somewhere...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me.

Just as a check that no multiplicative factors have got lost:

- suppose $X$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,3)$
- so $X$ has  $f(x)=\frac13$ and $F(x)=\mathbb P(X <x)=\frac x3$ on its support
- and $\mathbb{E}[X | X < c] =\frac c2$ when $0 < c< 3$ with derivative of $\frac12$
- while $\dfrac{f(c)\left(c -\mathbb{E}[X | X < c]\right)}{\mathbb P(X < c)} =\dfrac{\frac13(c-\frac c2)}{\frac c3}=\dfrac12$ too.